# Find the value of $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left( \frac{2^{-n^2}}{\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}2^{-k^2}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Find the value of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left( \frac{2^{-n^2}}{\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}2^{-k^2}}\right)$$

**My answer:**

Take $r_{n+1} = \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}2^{-k^2}$.

If $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left( \dfrac{2^{-n^2}}{\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}2^{-k^2}}\right)$ exists, then 
\begin{align*}
1+\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left( \dfrac{2^{-n^2}}{\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}2^{-k^2}}\right)&=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left( 1+\dfrac{2^{-n^2}}{\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}2^{-k^2}}\right)\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left( \dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}2^{-k^2}}{\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}2^{-k^2}}\right)\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{r_n}{r_{n+1}}=??
\end{align*}
 Moreover, I know $r_n$ is a remainder of the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-k^2}$, which is convergent.$~~~~\left(\mbox{ By ratio test,} ~~\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{2^{-(n+1)^2}}{2^{-n^2}}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{2.2^{2n}}=0<1 \right)$

Comment: both $r_n\to 0, r_{n+1}\to 0$, so it is indeterminate form of limit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $k \geq n+1$ it is easy to see that $n^{2}-k^{2} \leq -k$. Hence $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} 2^{n^{2}-k^{2}} \leq \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} 2^{-k} \to 0$. Hence the required limit is $\infty$.